# Select Latest Entered record in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement where I need to select average of records for a range of month of all dealers. But the condition here is, if one dealer does not have a record for particular month, then his latest record should be selected and added to the current month.

Requirement is: 
Select average of all dealers for the months between march and July.

condition which I wrote only takes average of all dealers for a month and does not consider laest entered record. Kindly let me know what can I do here.

My SQL:

```
select avg(dealer_score), month(end_time) as month from dealers where end_time>='2015-03-01' and end_time <= '2015-07-01 23:59:59' group by month(end_time)
```

Current Output

```
dealer_score | month
30 | March
90| July
```

Desired Output

```
dealer_score | month
30% | March
30% | April
30% | May
30% | June
90% | July
```

Records in the dealer table

```
dealer_id| dealer_name| dealer_score| end_time
1| abc| 30| '2015-03-01 20:00:00 00:00:00'
2| xyz| 30| '2015-03-01 21:00:00 00:00:00'
3| ABC| 90| '2015-07-01 23:00:00 00:00:00'
4| XYZ| 90| '2015-07-01 23:15:00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not exactly clear what you mean by borrowing records and why one month matters if the query is for a range.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extend the records for all five months, you can do something like:

```
select mon.mon,
       (if(@a2 := @a,
           if(@a := coalesce(avgds, @a), @a2, @a2), avgds)
       ) as avgds
from (select 3 as mon union all select 4 union all select 5 union all 
      select 6 union all select 7
     ) mon left join
     (select month(end_time) as mon, avg(dealer_score) as avgds
      from dealer
      group by month(end_time) 
     ) d
     on d.mon = m.mon cross join
     (select @a := 0) params
order by mon;
```

Comment: Thankyou. Can you please let me know whats 'a' here? and also I get this error 
"Unknown column 'm.mon' in 'field list'"

Comment: `@a` is a session variable.  The `m.mon` should be `mon.mon`.